# Illegal Access in WebappClassLoader.loadClass

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader

I have a task scheduler implemented in my application. Basically, what i do is schedule some task's to be executed 4 times in a day (like 6 in 6 hours), so the system schedules it to: 00:00, 06:00, 12:00, 18:00.

Ok, i have a class (FlowJobController) which extends the Thread class and in the run() implementation i keep sleeping the thread in 60 to 60 seconds, so it's executed again to check if there's any task to be executed. If true, i run my Job.

Basically the main part it:

```
rSet = pStmt.executeQuery();
while (rSet.next()) {
  long jobId = rSet.getLong("trf_codigo");
  String ruleName = rSet.getString("reg_nome");
  String ruleParameters = rSet.getString("trf_regra_parametros");

  Job job = new Job();
  job.setId(jobId);
  job.setRuleName(ruleName);
  job.setParameters(Functions.stringToList(ruleParameters, "\n"));

  FlowJob flowJob = new FlowJob(this, job);
  flowJob.start();
}
} catch (Exception ex) {
 logger.error(WFRSystem.DEFAULT_USER, system.getCode(), ex);
} finally {
  try {
    DBConnection.close(pStmt);
    DBConnection.close(rSet);

    // executede 60 in 60 sec
      Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
  } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      logger.error(WFRSystem.DEFAULT_USER, system.getCode(), ex);
  }
}
```

The thing is: When the pStmt.executeQUery() returns records to be executed, it goes into the while and the error appears into the line: `Job job = new Job();`

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "FlowJobController" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: wfr/com/Job
at wfr.com.FlowJobController.run(FlowJobController.java:112)
```

Before this error i got this error:

```
25/09/2012 12:00:09 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load wfr.com.Job.
```

The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:319)
at wfr.com.FlowJobController.run(FlowJobController.java:112)
```

The FlowJobController.java:112 is the `Job job = new Job();`

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your `wfr.com.Job` class did not may it into your war or other release package.

Comment: ... or your web app has been stopped/undeployed but your thread is still running.

Comment: Well, that sounds not possible (to not be in the war) since i'm running into the eclipse environment and it's in the class folder directory and no errors is shown about not finding those classes...

About the "web app" has been stopped, i don't know what is causing it

Answer (score 0):

> The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.

If you are saying that your code deliberately threw the `IllegalStateException` exception, then that is the likely cause of the subsequent problems.  If you throw an uncheck exception in static initialization, and that exception propagates, then the class initialization fails, and the class (and all classes that depend on it) are unusable.  In this case, it looks like it also caused the webapp to be stopped.

If this is the problem, the solution is "don't do that".  Fix whatever is causing the exception to be thrown.

---

The other possibility is that this is simply a missing class problem:

> Well, that sounds not possible (to not be in the war) since i'm running into the eclipse environment and it's in the class folder directory and no errors is shown about not finding those classes...

The class loader won't be looking in the Eclipse classes folder.  It will be looking in the webapp directory on your web container (Tomcat, Jetty, whatever).

Comment: It looks to me like the web app has already stopped. The IllegalStateException is a result of his thread trying to load a class via the (now invalid) web app classloader.

Comment: But, why is the web app is getting stopped? i shouldn't... everything has try catch and finally... i treat all thing's that supposed to happen

Comment: Good question, is there anything earlier in the logs, just as the app gets deployed. It must be getting part way through the deployment as it's starting your thread, maybe it fails after that?

Comment: @Saeger - perhaps you could update your question to make it clear what order the three message appear in the log file.  Right now, it is very unclear.  Also, please explain what the sentence I quoted means.